# Loop through enum value from User Data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to fetch my enum data from DetailUser Model. But it showing me error

> Attempt to read property "productive_status" on string

How I can fix this?
This is my code:

***edit.blade.php***

```
<select name="productive_status"id="productive_status" class="form-control select2" required>
     <option value="{{ '' }}" disabled selected>Choose</option>
           @foreach($detail_user as $key => $detail_user_item)
     <option value="{{ $detail_user_item->productive_status }}" {{ $detail_user_item->productive_status == $detail_user->productive_status ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $detail_user_item->productive_status }}</option>
           @endforeach
</select>

@if($errors->has('productive_status'))
    <p style="font-style: bold; color: red;">{{ $errors->first('productive_status') }}</p>
@endif
```

***DetailUser.php***

```
protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'type_user_id',
        'contact',
        'address',
        'pgps',
        'start_work_date',
        'years_of_service',
        'productive_status',
        'job_contract',
        'document',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at'
    ];
```

***UserController.php***

```
$role = Role::all()->pluck('title','id');
        $type_user = TypeUser::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
        $user->load('role');
        $detail_user = DetailUser::find($user['id']);

        return view('pages.backsite.management-access.user.edit', compact('user', 'role', 'type_user','detail_user'));
```

***DetailUserTable.php***

```
        $table->enum('productive_status', ['Productive','Pre Retirement','Retired'])->nullable();
```

Comment: You cannot do it using find , change to DetailUser::where('id',$user['id'])->get()

Comment: @Xun Still not what I want. Actually, I realize, that I should make productive_status a new independent table as child from detail_user